# How can we have real void pointer to const?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, declaration

I am experimenting with C, I have declared a void pointer to const. In normal pointer to const, we cannot change the value of address its pointing by dereferencing it. But if we use a void pointer to const it can be changed. Similar behavior is seen for constant pointer, a void constant pointer's address can be changed! Is this the expected behavior? or am I missing something? I am using following code:

```
const void *ptr2; //pointer to const 
void const *ptr3; // const pointer 
uint32_t modNum32 = 0xDEADBEEF;
ptr2 = &modNum32;
*((uint32_t*)ptr2) = 4; // this works!
printf("After modifying a void pointer to const: %X, This don't work with normal pointer to const\n",modNum32);

ptr3 = &modNum32;
*((uint32_t*)ptr3) = 5; //This works as expected 
printf("%X\n",modNum32);

printf("Address of void const pointer before incrementing %p\n",ptr3);
ptr3++;//this works!
printf("Address of void const pointer after incrementing %p! this don't work in normal const pointers\n",ptr3);
```

Below is the console O/P:

```
After modifying a void pointer to const: 4, This don't work with normal pointer to const
5
Address of void const pointer before incrementing 0x7ffe61cf0710
Address of void const pointer after incrementing 0x7ffe61cf0711! this don't work in normal const pointers
```

Comment: Side: `const void *` and `void const *` are synonymous. They both declare a mutable pointer to constant void. However, `void const *` and `void * const` are *not* synonymous. The former declares a mutable pointer to constant void, the latter declares a constant pointer to mutable void (and requires initialization, lest you enjoy compile-time errors. when in doubt, check [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org)).

Comment: `(uint32_t*)ptr2` is a new pointer that is not a pointer to const

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration

```
void const *ptr3; // const pointer
```

does not declare a constant pointer. To declare a constant pointer you need to write

```
void * const ptr3 = &modNum32; // const pointer
```

Pay attention to that you need to initialize it explicitly if is a block scope declaration.

In this expression statement

```
*((uint32_t*)ptr2) = 4; // this works!
```

you discarded the qualifier const.

As the pointed object is not a constant object then you can change it.

You should write

```
*(( const uint32_t*)ptr2) = 4;
```

to prevent modification. In this case the compiler will issue an error.

Node: a declaration of a constant pointer to a constant object will look like

```
const void * const ptr1 = &modNum32;
```

Comment: `As the pointed object is not a constant object then you can change it.` But this don't work in case of normal pointer to constant, right? though the pointed object is variable, we cannot change its value by dereferencing... For example: this declaration: `const uint32_t *ptr2 = &modNum32`. In this I cannot modify the value of modNum32 because its pointer to constant

Comment: @Noob USing this pointer you can not to change the pointed object.

Comment: so does it mean in case of void pointer to const without `constant` qualifier I can change the value by deferencing?

Comment: @Noob I have not understood the question.  If the pointed object is a constant object you may not change it.